# Fortigate PPTP default gateway configuration

Tags: vpn, fortigate

I have a fortigate 40C running with a PPTP configuration. My VPN works partly. I can connect to the office network, however I can't get the default gateway working. Can anyone help me with figuring out whats wrong with this configuration, please?

```
config firewall address
edit "all"
next
edit "Internal_Range"
set subnet 192.168.6.0 255.255.255.0
next
edit "PPTP"
set associated-interface "wan1"
set type iprange
set end-ip 192.168.6.180
set start-ip 192.168.6.160
next
end
config firewall policy
edit 1
set srcintf "internal"
set dstintf "wan1"
set srcaddr "all"
set dstaddr "all"
set action accept
set schedule "always"
set service "ANY"
set nat enable
next
edit 50
set srcintf "wan1"
set dstintf "internal"
set srcaddr "PPTP"
set dstaddr "all"
set action accept
set schedule "always"
set service "ANY"
next
edit 4
set srcintf "wan1"
set dstintf "wan1"
set srcaddr "PPTP"
set dstaddr "all"
set action accept
set schedule "always"
set service "ANY"
set nat enable
next
end
config vpn pptp
set status enable
set eip 192.168.6.180
set sip 192.168.6.160
set usrgrp "Wizard_users"
end
config system dhcp server
edit 1
set default-gateway 192.168.6.1
set domain "lan"
set interface "internal"
config ip-range
edit 1
set end-ip 192.168.6.159
set start-ip 192.168.6.100
next
end
set lease-time 345600
set netmask 255.255.255.0
set dns-server1 192.168.6.1
next
end
config system interface
edit "wan1"
set vdom "root"
set mode pppoe
set allowaccess ping
set type physical
set alias "FTTB Fixed IP"
set username "X@X"
set password ENC X
set defaultgw enable
set dns-server-override disable
next
edit "modem"
set vdom "root"
set mode pppoe
set type physical
next
edit "ssl.root"
set vdom "root"
set type tunnel
next
edit "internal"
set vdom "root"
set ip 192.168.6.1 255.255.255.0
set allowaccess ping https ssh
set type physical
set alias "LAN"
next
end
```

The internal IP range is 192.168.6.0/24. The Fortigate has the IP 192.168.6.1 and is also the DNS Server. The VPN range is 192.168.6.160-180

Comment: Just a minor thing, for all practical purposes PPTP is completely broken and should never be used any more.